# Bash script executing command with file lines as parameters

Tags: bash, shell

This file has the parameters:

```
root@moodle:/usr/src# cat plugins_filtered 
--release 2019042008 mod_bigbluebuttonbn
--release 2020020500 mod_hvp
--release 2020043003 block_xp
```

This are the commands I would like to execute:

```
root@moodle:/usr/src# while read in; do echo moosh plugin-install "$in"; done < /usr/src/plugins_filtered
moosh plugin-install --release 2019042008 mod_bigbluebuttonbn
moosh plugin-install --release 2020020500 mod_hvp
moosh plugin-install --release 2020043003 block_xp
```

If I go one by one everything works, if I remove the ok, I get errors:

```
root@moodle:/usr/src# while read in; do moosh plugin-install "$in"; done < /usr/src/plugins_filtered
Option 'release' requires a value.
Moosh global options should be passed before command not after it.Option 'release' requires a value.
Moosh global options should be passed before command not after it.Option 'release' requires a value.
Moosh global options should be passed before command not after it.root@moodle:/usr/src#
```

Comment: Did you try `<plugins_filtered xargs -l1 bash -c 'moosh plugin-install "$@"' _`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
while read in; do echo moosh plugin-install "$in" | bash; done < /usr/src/plugins_filtered
```